# Vector of iterators to unordered map - compilation error

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Hey fellow programmers

I want to create a vector of iterators to unordered map for elements which fulfill some criterion. I've written a function for that, but it doesn't compile, and I don't understand what's wrong with the code:

```
class Cache
{
public:
    Cache()
    {}

    template<typename Functor>
    std::vector<Transaction::TransactionsContainer::iterator> getSpecificOrders(Functor criterion) const;

protected:
    Transaction::TransactionsContainer transactions;
};

template<typename Functor>
std::vector<Transaction::TransactionsContainer::iterator> Cache::getSpecificOrders(Functor criterion) const
{
   std::vector<Transaction::TransactionsContainer::iterator> foundOrders;
   for (auto it = transactions.begin(); it != transactions.end(); ++it)
   {
       if (criterion(it->second))
       {
           foundOrders.push_back(it);//this line fails to compile
       }
   }
   return foundOrders;
}
```

compiler reports error about failed conversion; the example is here
https://onlinegdb.com/SyHXHFm2P

Please explain me what I did wrong.

Error message:

```
In file included from main.cpp:9:0:
cache.h: In member function ‘std::vector<std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Transaction::Order>, false, true> > Cache::getSpecificOrders(Functor) const’:
cache.h:25:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector, Transaction::Order>, false, true> >::push_back(std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>&)’
            foundOrders.push_back(it);
                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/vector:64:0,
                 from cache.h:2,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:914:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::__detail::_Node_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>; _Alloc = std::allocator, Transaction::Order>, false, true> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::__detail::_Node_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:914:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::__detail::_Node_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>&}’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:932:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::__detail::_Node_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>; _Alloc = std::allocator, Transaction::Order>, false, true> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::__detail::_Node_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:932:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>’ to ‘std::vector, Transaction::Order>, false, true> >::value_type&& {aka std::__detail::_Node_iterator, Transaction::Order>, false, true>&&}’
```

Comment: Put a [mcve] and error messages as verbatim text in your quesiton as required here please. Links to external repositories are not acceptable.

Comment: The [mcve] is still missing! [Edit] again please.

Comment: Don't you see the link?

Comment: I told you that links aren't acceptable. Links can rot, but this site is supposed to be self contained.

Comment: You totally seem to miss the point. I can't [copy your code and reproduce those error messages you claim](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7319a5a73a4350b).. We're not interested in a full definition of all that `Transaction`namespace stuff, but an example that reproduces that specific error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSpecificOrders` is declared `const`; therefore `transactions` within that function is a `const` object; therefore `transactions.begin()` returns `Transaction::TransactionsContainer::const_iterator`. You are trying to add that to the vector of `Transaction::TransactionsContainer::iterator`, but the former is not convertible to the latter.

Comment: I figured that on my own when I've split the error message to separate lines, but I'll give you the credit for the answer mate anyway.